# Setup a MVC/MVW system in python with tkinter

Tags: python, model-view-controller, module, tkinter

I would like to split my code in several files because I can't find my way through anymore.
I decided to write one file that only creates the GUI, like so:

```
# userinterface.py

class Userinterface(object):
    def __init__(self, controller):
        self.controller = controller
        self.buildGUI()
        return

    def buildGUI():
        # build lots of widgets and stuff
        widget = tk.Thewidget(options=values, command=self.controller.onclick)
```

The functions to read all relevant entries depending on what the user asks for as well as calculations and interpretation of calculated data should happen in a different file/module. So I create one object that will represent my controlset. Then, I'll create the GUI and hand over the controlset-object, so the GUI knows who to ask to perform any actions. Like so:

```
    # main.py
    import userinterface as gui

    class Controls(object):
        def onclick(self):
            # read values from widgets and do stuff
            var1 = GUI.widget_entry.get()
            # Call some other function with var1 etc.

if __name__ == '__main__':
    GUI_controls = Controls()
    GUI = gui.UserInterface(GUI_controls)
```

Everything work well, but is this the right way to continue? There will be other modules and files coming into play. As far as I understood, the GUI_controls-object can send and receive data from all different modules and thereby manage the program.

Is this what is meant with Model-View-Whatever/Model-View-Controller? (MVW/MVC)
Or is there a better concept to approach this?